# Tangent bundle of $S^2$ not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to show that the tangent bundle of $S^2$ not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$. This is from an exam, where there is a hint stating that this is more than showing that $TS^2$ is non-trivial.

I know how to show the hairy ball theorem, according to which $TS^n$ is non-trivial iff n is even.

I also know that a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ of rank $m$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is trivial (by definition) iff there exists a diffeomorphism $f:E\rightarrow M\times \mathbb{R}^m$ such that for every $p\in M$, $f$ induces a vector space isomorphism $f:\pi^{-1}(p)\rightarrow \{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^m$.

So I see that showing that $TS^2$ is non-trivial only guarantees that $TS^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ via a diffeomorphism satisfying the property above, but it is not enough to conclude that there isn't any diffeomorphism.

How can I show this then?

Comment: What you state as the hairy ball theorem is not true! In fact, $TS^n$ is trivial iff $n=0, 1, 3$, or $7$. What you mean to say is that $S^n$ has a nonvanishing vector field iff $n$ is odd.

Comment: Relevant link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92337/total-spaces-of-ts2-and-s2-times-r2-not-homeomorphic

Comment: Euler characteristic computes the self-intersection number of the image of the zero section which is a generator of 2nd homology group. The self-intersection number is a topological invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that relies on a theorem of Kervaire with a somewhat-involved proof (I think the particular case of $n=k=2$ is probably much easier, but I couldn't find such a proof to confirm my suspicions.)

> Theorem: The normal bundle to an $n$-sphere embedded inside $\Bbb R^{n+k}$ is trivial if $k> \frac{n+1}2$

This implies any 2-sphere embedded in $S^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ has a tubular neighborhood isomorphic (as fiber bundles) to $  S^2 \times \Bbb R^2$, since $S^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ embeds as an open manifold of $\Bbb R^4$. If $f:TS^2\rightarrow S^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ is a diffeomorphism, then the image of the zero section has a trivial tubular neighborhood  $N$ by the above disscussion, but then $f^{-1}(N)$ is a trivial tubular neighborhood of the zero section in $TS^2$.

References:

- Massey's  *On the Normal Bundle of a Sphere Imbedded in Euclidean Space*
- Kervaire's *An Interpretation of G. Whitehead's Generalization of H. Hopf's Invariant*

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try this.

$S^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is trivial, while $TS^2$ is not trivial because only the spheres of odd dimension have non-trivial tangent bundle (Hopf's theorem). So they can't be diffeomorphic.

Comment: This is exactly what mike said in the comment.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily follow.  Two different bundle structures can have diffeomorphic total spaces.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Could you give an example of such a situation?

Comment: @JohnMars:  Sure.  Consider $S^1$ bundles over $S^2\times S^2$.  They are classified by their Euler class, an element $e\in H^2(S^2\times S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$.  If we select $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then the total space $E_{a,b}$ is a simply connected $5$-manifold with $H^2(E)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  From Barden-Smale, there are only two diffeomorphism types of such $5$-manifolds (determined by their second Stiefel-Whitney class).  So, countably many bundles fall into at most $2$ total space types.

Comment: @JohnMars:  The is also a classification of $S^3$-bundles over $S^4$ by Crowley and Escher https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004147.  It turns out that $S^7$ appears as the total space for multiple distinct bundles.  I didn't go through their congruences in detail, but I think it actually appears infinitely many times.

Answer (score -4):

I think that if suppose that exist a diffeomorphism $F$ then there is an correspondence between sections in $S^{2}\times\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and vector fields on $TS^{2}$. Take the constant section $s(x)=(x,(1,0))$ and by diffeomorphism there is $X\epsilon\mathfrak{X}(S^{2})$ such that $dF(s)=X$, but this section vanishing in south pole under stereographic proyection, that means $dF$ isnt isomorphism