# Are $T\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ different?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, tangent-bundle

I have seen the claim that $T\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ are not diffeomorphic, but I have only ever seen the proof that they are not isomorphic as vector bundles (which is a cute application of the hairy ball theorem). How would I prove that they are indeed not diffeomorphic (or better, not homeomorphic)?

Comment: Incidentally, this question has a duplicate [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893519/tangent-bundle-of-s2-not-diffeomorphic-to-s2-times-mathbbr2?rq=1) with different answers, as well as a [duplicate on Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92337/total-spaces-of-ts2-and-s2-times-r2-not-homeomorphic) with yet another set of different answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's start by examining the unit tangent bundle $US^2 \subset TS^2$ (i.e. the set of all tangent vectors of unit length) and its analogue $S^1\times S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^2$. Observe that the action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$ extends to $US^2$, and this action is transitive and has trivial stabilizer, so it induces a diffeomorphism $SO(3)\to US^2$.  It follows that
$$
\pi_1(US^2) \;\cong\; \pi_1\bigl(SO(3)\bigr) \;\cong\; \mathbb{Z}_2.
$$
Then $US^2$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^2$, since $\pi_1(S^1\times S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, to prove that $X = TS^2$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^2$ are not homeomorphic, let $X\cup\{\infty\}$ and $Y\cup\{\infty\}$ denote their one point compactifications.  I claim that
$$
H_2(X\cup\{\infty\},X) \;\cong\; H_1(US^2) \;\cong\; \mathbb{Z}_2\tag*{(1)}
$$
and
$$
H_2(Y\cup\{\infty\},Y) \;\cong\; H_1(S^1\times S^2) \;\cong\; \mathbb{Z}.\tag*{(2)}
$$
To see the isomorphism in (1), let $S \subset TS^2$ denote the canonical copy of $S^2$ in $TS^2$, i.e. the set of zero tangent vectors.  By excision
$$
H_2(X\cup\{\infty\},X) \;\cong\; H_2(X\cup\{\infty\}-S,X-S)
$$
But $X\cup\{\infty\}-S$ is clearly contractible, so
$$
H_2(X\cup\{\infty\}-S,X-S) \;\cong\; H_1(X-S)
$$
by the long exact sequence for the pair $(X\cup\{\infty\}-S,X-S)$.  But $X-S$ deformation retracts onto $US^2$, so $H_1(X-S) \cong H_1(US^2)$, as desired.  A similar argument establishes the isomorphism in (2).

Comment: More simply, SO(3) act transitively and without fixed points on the unit circle bundle of $S^2$.  So(3) is not the Cartesian product the the sphere with a circle. E.G. its fundamental group is $Z_2$ since $S^3$ is a 2 fold cover.

Comment: @JoeS:  It's not clear to me that this works.  If two total spaces of vector bundles happen to be diffeomorphic, does that necessarily imply their sphere bundles are also diffeomorphic?