# The tangent bundle $TS^n$ is diffeomorphic the $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry, manifolds

The tangent bundle $TS^n$ is diffeomorphic the $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

**Comments:** I was able to show that $TS^1$ is diffeomorphic the $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. For the case $n=2$, I believe it is not true, but I do not know how to justify it.

Comment: what was you diffeomorphic map for the case $n=1$?

Comment: Hint: hairy ball theorem.

Comment: @Wojowu We posted at the exact same time.

Comment: @Arian the map: $(p, \lambda \frac{d}{dt}(p)) \mapsto (p,\lambda)$

Comment: @Croos: Although it's not the subject of your question, showing $TS^1$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ takes a bit more work than the map you posted in the comment above: that only works locally.

Comment: @Croos  Just so you know, this story about for which $n$ we have $TS^n=S^n \times \mathbb{R^n}$ will get you very quickly into deep mathematics. Persue it!

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323740/are-t-mathbbs-2-and-mathbbs-2-times-mathbbr2-different if one only cares about the case of even $n$.

Answer (score -2):

Hint: It's the hairy ball theorem.