# tangent bundle that isn't diffeomorphic to the Cartesian product

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

I am studying the notion of tangent bundle $TM$ of a smooth manifold $M$,and in my textbook I am acknowledged that for most smooth manifold of dimension $n$,it's not true that $TM$ is diffeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb R^n$.I failed to give a simple example.I noticed that there is a set-theorical bijective correspondence between the to space,which makes it more difficult to understand why the diffeomorphism fails in general.Is there anyone to help?

Comment: Have you learned about Euler class ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323740/are-t-mathbbs-2-and-mathbbs-2-times-mathbbr2-different

Comment: Note that pure set-theoretic considerations is mostly useless in DG/DT context --- every manifold of positive dimension is going to have cardinality $c$ (because it is a countable union of $\mathbb{R}^n$).  Problems are almost always in the topological aspect.